# Why a Javascript function call doesn't work after changing visibility from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind, dom-events

I have image with this two JS functions:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" visible="false">
<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/....png" 
                    onmouseover="someFunc();" onmouseout="someFunc2();" />
<div/>
```

When I click on some button I change `myDiv` `visible` to `true`.
But then `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` doesn't work.
If `myDiv` is visible by default then it works.
So what to do to made this two functions calls to w
ork after I change visibility?
This is in update panel and visibility is changed via ajax.

Comment: what version of ASP.Net you use? Also do you use jQuery?

Comment: I am using asp.net 3.5, no JQuery

Comment: Check my answer. may be helpful for you

Comment: controls with `Visible=false;` are not rendered in the html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, use setting `display:none` in code behind instead of `Visible=false`

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">
<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/....png" 
                    onmouseover="someFunc();" onmouseout="someFunc2();" />
<div/>
```

In code behind

```
myDiv.Style["display"] = "none";// hide
myDiv.Style["display"] = "block";//show
//myDiv.visible=false;// dont work
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (by default hidden)

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="display:none;">
<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/....png" 
                onmouseover="someFunc();" onmouseout="someFunc2();" />
<div/>
```

inside your buttons Click event which i guess is in code behind

```
protected void youBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(your condition) // show
   {
      myDiv.Attributes.Add("style","display:block");
   }
   else // hide
   {
     myDiv.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net doesn't render elements that are not visible. This saves bytes.

This happens only for server elements. You can fix this by making it a client element only by removing the 'runat="server"'.
You can hide the element by using `display: none`

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/....png" 
                    onmouseover="someFunc();" onmouseout="someFunc2();" />
<div/>
```

Comment: But I have to use runat=server because I show hide this from code behind.

Comment: You cannot show elements hidden from code behind without a PostBack. Make sure that your page refreshes when you make the div visible

Comment: But when I set visible to true the whole div is shown (it's in UpdatePanel) it just onmouseover and onmouseout that display tooltip doesn't work.

Comment: did you debug with a tool like firebug? There is a good changes that those functions are being called, but something in that is probably using a framework like jquery, that would not behave well with elements added by an UpdatePanel.

Comment: I have this in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timer' of undefined
tooltip.hide
onmouseout. But on this happens only to divs where I set in code behind visible to true. On the same page there are already visible items that use the same functions and those works fine :(